# XFCE empathy notification icon

Tags: 11.10, empathy, notification-area, messaging-menu

I'm using empathy in xfce4, and I appear to be having both a notification icon as well as the messaging menu.
Is it possible to hide the notification icon?

Screenshot:
[image]

I'm using 11.10

Comment: well... and what is your problem / question now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empathy does not have such a setting.

But you can configure the xfce notification area to hide specific icons:

Just right click on an empty space of the panel, click on panel and on the following dialog, locate the 'notification area' on the 'objects' tab and check the checkbox under column 'hidden'.